# Why do edits to another users' post have to change at least 6 characters?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, editing

In several posts, I found one single mistake which in some cases, was crucial to the meaning of the sentence (with commas, especially) or at least very irritating. While I tried to eliminate the mistake in an otherwise quite flawless post, I always got the message that edits below an extent of 6 characters weren't possible. I then had to cancel the edit and leave the mistake where it was. Of course, now that my reputation is sufficient to edit posts without reviewing, I could change at random 6 other characters and reedit them to their former state afterwards, but this would seem a strange workaround to me. I can change one single character in my own posts, so why isn't it possible with the other ones?

Addendum: I just found this post *to be a duplicate of [this question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/error-edits-need-to-be-at-least-6-characters?rq=1)*, save that in my opinion, this former question doesn't seem to have received a fully satisfactory answer. When I see an obvious single fault in a text, I don't think it is fussy to correct it in the first place, nor do I find it reasonable to conclude that I now have to draw my full attention to the whole of the post, regardless of my intentions or qualifications as to its special content, or field of expertise. As I understand it, this is always intended to be a collaborative effort where also small contributions count.

I have found another issue concerning this, as Takkats answer to the older question includes the remark that with a reputation of more than 1000 also edits minor than 6 characters were possible – from my experience, I can't confirm this so far.

Comment: I would transfer this question as an answer to the aforesaid older question, but I think it would hardly be an answer but an acknowledgement of the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 6-character limit for edits was introduced for good reasons for all Stack Exchange Sites including us. I doubt this will change on a per site basis. Lowering this limit would need a change made to all sites on the network.

See:

- [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

  and many more [posts on this topic on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=edit%206%20character).

Comment: Then remains the issue of the >1000 privilege to edit even single characters in posts not one's own, which I couldn't verify so far. But strangely enough, when I tried to demonstrate this on your post, I failed to do so because it worked. So the item seems resolved.

Comment: Interesting... for the first time I saw the `[Edit removed during grace period]` notice... did not even know that such a grace period exists with edits.